# iPad app on MBA maverics

Tags: itunes

Compatibility question
I want to download the BBC iPlayer from the iTunes store on my Mac Book Air (10.9), but it is only available for iPad or iPhone as shown here:

[image: iTunes storee]

Can I still somehow use it on my MBA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can't.

IPAs downloaded from the App Store are built for the ARM processor in actual iOS devices. Even if you signed up as a developer which would give you access to the iPhone Simulator, it's not an emulator and can't run ARM code.

The only way you can run iOS apps on OS X is if you have the iPhone Simulator and have a version of the app specifically compiled to run on the simulator.